# CiviCRM in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, translation

I'm trying out CiviCRM and searching the internet I found you guys.

Using Wordpress and installed CiviCRM, but want it in Portuguese. I've read many doc's and found nothing. I have pt_BR.mo and SQL file, already put in appropriate places and nothing works.

They could give me a hand? Indicate a doc/manual, anything so that I can analyze the CiviCRM and put him in Portuguese.

thanks
kklo

Comment: it would help us help you if you provide more info of what you have read. did you try https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/the-civicrm-community/localising-civicrm/

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to :

1. Download the language files from [SF](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=177914) (it seems you have already done this)
2. Unpack the language-tarball in wp-content/plugins/civicrm. it creates subdirectories civicrm/i10n and civicrm/l18n with several files
3. Login to CiviCRM and Go to Administer » Localization » Languages, Currency, Locations
4. Enable Portuguese as default language

Beleza, should be working!

More details can be found here:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/i18n+Administrator's+Guide:+Using+CiviCRM+in+your+own+language

Comment: OK
I had created the subdirectories CiviCRM/i10n and downloaded from https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.7.4-l10n.tar.gz?src=donate and copied all the files in in /l10n and put the files SQL directory /CiviCRM/CiviCRM/sql.

I found no files to CiviCRM/l18n directory. Where do I download it?